# How to prevent a flex item from shrinking smaller than its content?

Tags: html, flexbox

I've set up a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x0eo3aeo/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="flexCol1">aaa</div>
    <div class="flexCol2"><div style="width:100px; background-color:yellow;">bbb</div></div>
    <div class="flexCol3"><div style="width:250px; background-color:pink;">Hello world, some long text here to make this element stay at 250px while splitting onto multiple lines.</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.flexCol1, .flexCol3 {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Firefox actually behaves exactly how I want.  Columns 1 and 3 flex equally *until* the width of column 3 hits the fixed size of its child `div`, and then only column 1 is flexed.  However, in Chrome, both columns continue to flex equally and the child content of column 3 overflows.

Is there a way to achieve the Firefox-style behaviour in a cross-browser way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the Firefox behavior in Chrome by adding `min-width: -webkit-min-content;` to `.flexCol3`. This prevents it from shrinking below its min-content width.  (This is what's supposed to happen by default, due to `min-width:auto` introduced in the flexbox spec, but that [hasn't been implemented in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898) yet.)

As noted in comments below, IE doesn't seem to have a `min-content` width keyword implemented, so you might have to do something hackier there (like `min-width: 250px`). Fortunately, IE's next release (12?) does have `min-width:auto` implemented, so this should Just Work like Firefox there, I'm told.

Comment: Nice ideas, but neither of them worked for me.  Could you point to updated jsfiddles where your ideas are implemented?

Comment: Actually I tell a lie; the `min-width: -webkit-min-content;` did fix it in Chrome, but what about in IE11?  And also, can you point to a jsfiddle of the `flex:1 0` idea working please?

Comment: Ah -- sorry, you're right, "flex:1 0" doesn't work. I was mistakenly thinking that flexCol3 had its flex-basis set to "auto", and that zeroing out flex-basis would prevent it from shrinking -- but no, its flex-basis is 0, from the "flex" shorthand.

Comment: I'm not sure about an IE solution, sorry. :-/  It looks like they don't have a "min-content" keyword implemented, according to http://caniuse.com/#search=min-content .  But I'm told they do have `min-width:auto` working in the next IE release, so this should Just Work there.  (Strawman suggestion: you could of course use `min-width: 250px` instead of `-webkit-min-content`, and that'd work in IE -- but I'm guessing that in practice, you don't know whether the value is 250px or something else.)

Comment: (Sorry, 2 comments up when I said "zeroing out flex-basis", I meant "zeroing out flex-shrink". Stackoverflow isn't letting me edit that comment anymore; hence, posting this one as a correction.)

Comment: flex: auto; seems to be working in CefSharp for me.